# Override default talkback announcement of SeekBar

Tags: android, accessibility, seekbar, talkback

Applying accessibility content description for `Seekbar` in `setOnSeekBarChangedListener` and talkback is reading the seek bar rating status in percentage then the content description eg "100% 10 rating very satisfied"

**What id did**
Calling this function from `onProgressChanged` and `onStopTrackingTouch`

Here is code snapshot of function

```
void setAccessibilityTextForView(View mSeekBar, String msg) {
    if (AccessibilityHandler.isAccessibilityEnabled(this)) {
        if (mSeekBar != null) {
            mSeekBar.setContentDescription(msg)

        }
    }
}
```

Actual Result : "100% 10 Rating very satisfied"
Expectation: Talkback should ready only the content description I've applied eg "10 rating very satisfied"

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you rather use the [documentation for `stateDescription`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setStateDescription(java.lang.CharSequence)) API:

> A state description briefly describes the states of the view and is primarily used for accessibility support to determine how the states of a view should be presented to the user. It is a supplement to the boolean states (for example, checked/unchecked) and it is used for customized state description (for example, "wifi, connected, three bars"). **State description changes frequently while content description should change less often**.

It seems to indicate that `stateDescription` should be the one that gets updated more regularly.

I don't know what version of slider you are using or why it's not a `RatingBar` (which I know in XML Views inherits from SeekBar) - but I think I can help you out anyway.

I think the problem is that you aren't setting the stateDescription:

1. on init
2. on change

```
    private fun setSeekBarStateDescription() {
        ViewCompat.setStateDescription(
            seekbar,
            when {
                seekbar.progress <= 20 -> "1 star"
                seekbar.progress in 21..40 -> "2 star"
                seekbar.progress in 41..60 -> "3 star"
                seekbar.progress in 61..80 -> "4 star"
                else -> "5 stars"

            }
        )
    }
    

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_rating_bar)

        ...

        seekbar.apply {
            setSeekBarStateDescription()
            setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : OnSeekBarChangeListener {
                override fun onProgressChanged(
                    seekBar: SeekBar?,
                    progress: Int,
                    fromUser: Boolean
                ) {
                    setSeekBarStateDescription()
                }

                override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) = Unit

                override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) = Unit
            })
        }
    }
```

My XML looks like this:

```
        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:max="100"
            />
```

And the output I get seems to be what you are expecting:

[image: A simple Android app with a rating bar - up and down gestures are used to demonstrate the rating bar being changed, and TalkBack's announcement is '1 star', '2 star' in relation to the position of the slider]